# How to add a shortcut directly to the 'Alarms' and 'World Clock' tabs of the stock HTC Clock app?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, alarm, clock

I have QCustomShortcut installed and I'd like to be able to create a shortcut directly to the 'Alarms' and 'World Clock' tabs of my HTC stock Clock app (com.htc.android.worldclock).

- The app has an activity called com.htc.android.worldclock.AlarmClock but creating a shortcut to that doesn't work.

I have already tried the following apps but they just open the Clock app on the first tab instead of the third:

1. Alarm shortcut by Alexandr Ivanov
2. Alarms shortcut by Matthieu Guenebaud
3. Alarm Clock Launcher by Slipstream Apps

It should just be a case of defining the correct action, package and class in QCustomShortcut but I'm stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: Can nobody help? No pointers?